# imagemagick on nitrous cloud ide

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, nitrousio

i´m very happy with the Nitrous product, but I have a truly doubt..

I´m developing in Ruby on Rails and read about the already installed Imagemagick at the system… in the Image Tools package..

I´m using the paperclip gem, and **would like to know how to declare the path that Imagemagick is installed at the NITROUS.IO system**.. http://help.nitrous.io/box-interpreters-and-tools/

Like **“c:\Imagemagick”** … usually declared at the **config/environment** folder…

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Thank you so much, 
Best regards, 
Miguel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the instructions on:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor

If you run:

```
which convert
```

From the terminal on your [Nitrous.IO](https://www.nitrous.io/) box, then you should see the correct PATH for imagemagick:

```
/usr/bin/convert
```